# Exclude a field or model from a django haystack search

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, django-cms

I've implemented search using django-haystack & I've been unable to find if/how you can exclude a specific field type or model from search.

Several models across my apps use a certain model field which only allows `filter()` and `exclude()` queries so when I've ran my first test of Haystack I've had a `TypeError` raised by the model field as Haystack is running an `icontains` query.

So I've got a model that looks like this;

```
class LatestNews(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        _("Title"),
        max_length=255
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(
        max_length=255,
        db_index=True,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=_('Auto generated')
    )
    image = ImageUploaderField(
        _("Header Image"),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    body = PlaceholderField('news')
```

And I tried to define `indexed=False` in my `search_indexes.py` for that app but the TypeError is still raised;

```
class NewsIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(
        document=True,
        use_template=True
    )
    title = indexes.CharField(
        model_attr='title'
    )
    image = indexes.CharField(indexed=False)

    def get_model(self):
        return LatestNews
```

I'm not sure if my understanding of the search_indexes field definition is wrong, but is it possible to exclude a field type or model from all Haystack searches?